# show icoin in taskbar

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I just had a problem, that is i want to change icon on my app but it only change icon in form and not change icon in taskbar. I want to change icon all

### My code

```
Public Function gIconLoad(ByRef frm As System.Windows.Forms.Form, ByVal iconpath As String) As Boolean

    gIconLoad = False

    'UPGRADE_WARNING: Dir に新しい動作が指定されています。 詳細については、'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="9B7D5ADD-D8FE-4819-A36C-6DEDAF088CC7"' をクリックしてください。
    If System.IO.File.Exists(iconpath) Then
        'UPGRADE_WARNING: オブジェクト frm.Icon の既定プロパティを解決できませんでした。 詳細については、'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"' をクリックしてください。
        Dim hIcon As IntPtr = ExtractAssociatedIconA(frm.Handle, iconpath, 0)
        frm.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(hIcon)

    Else
        '        MsgBox "アイコン（ " + iconpath + " ）が見つかりません", vbExclamation
        Exit Function
    End If
    gIconLoad = True

End Function
```

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6cTt.jpg)

Comment: Icon, displayed in taskbar, sets in Solution properties at "Application" tab (look for "Icon and manifest").

Comment: @Auditive no i want to set icoin in code not set in "Application" tab

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you choose to use PInvoke `ExtractAssociatedIconA` function instead on provided `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon`. With second one icon sets without any problem:

```
'Rewrited function into procedure from your example
Public Sub SetIcon(ByRef form As Form, ByVal iconPath As String)

    If IO.File.Exists(iconPath) Then
        form.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(iconPath)
    End If

End Sub
```

Complete:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    ' Setting icon on provided form (current) 
    Private Sub OnFormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SetIcon(sender, "MyAwesomeIcon.ico")
    End Sub

   'Rewrited function into procedure from your example
    Public Sub SetIcon(ByRef form As Form, ByVal iconPath As String)

        If IO.File.Exists(iconPath) Then
            form.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(iconPath)
        End If

    End Sub

    'This PInvoke function not neccessary, you can use Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path) instead
    <DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Shared Function ExtractAssociatedIconA(ByVal hInst As IntPtr,
                                           ByVal iconPath As StringBuilder,
                                           ByRef index As Short) As IntPtr
    End Function
       
End Class
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: tks all, i had found solution
In my win 10 os, taskbar is setting always hide lable so in my app icoin changed in form but not change in taskbar. I changed to in setting taskbar to when taskbar is full or never and it work.